# Custom SoapFault in PHP

Tags: php, exception, soap

I was wondering if it's possible to catch custom SoapFaults in PHP. I can't get this piece of code working:

```
class UAC_ValidationFault extends SoapFault{
    public function __construct($code, $message){
        parent::__construct($code, $message);
   }
}
```

So in my webservice I throw an error this way:

```
throw new UAC_ValidationFault("666", "Test error");
```

When I try to catch this error, I want to know the Classname of the custom error, but it's always "SoapFault":

```
try{
     $return = $client->testErrorThrow('bogus'); // $client is SoapClient instance
     print_r($return);
}
catch(UAC_ValidationFault $e){
     var_dump(get_class($e));  // isn't catched
}
catch(Exception $e){
     var_dump(get_class($e)); // returns "SoapFault"
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I can't remember, but I think if you do a `print_r` or `var_dump` on the `$e` exception object then you will get more information. You can then use the error code (`$code`) to work out where the error has come from perhaps.

Comment: I know, but there's no mention at all of "UAC_ValidationFault" in the var_dump/print_r of the thrown error. It's like PHP only wants to throw native SoapFaults.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a wrapped class of SoapClient. Catch the SoapFault, then according the the error_code throw your custom Exception.

Comment: Not possible, the service will be used by a .NET application. They will handle my Exceptions via soap directly.

Comment: AFAIK, The .NET application can not know your Exception defined in your sever side. What they can do is to get the error code and throw their custom Exception.

Comment: Unless you define it in your WSDL?

Comment: Yes, Exceptions are platform independent, they can't be translated from one to another.

Comment: Well, in that case, is there a way to make my code work with some additions in the WSDL?

Comment: So you should define your custom exception as a fault element in WSDL.